# Need help determining whether or not to drop ship an item and how to reduce number of shipments

Tags: c#, decision-tree

I've used this forum for reference for many years but this is my first time posting. I hope someone can help!

I am trying to write code that will take some rules into consideration and decide where to ship items from (either from my warehouse or from a drop shipper).  Here's an example of how the possibilities could look:

```
HQ = My headquarters, the preferred warehouse to ship from
WH1-3 = Drop shippers
Numbers in each column = available quantity at that location

Assume for each Item (2) need to be shipped to the customer.

          HQ    WH1    WH2    WH3
Item 1    0     2      0      0
Item 2    2     0      6      0
Item 3    1     0      3      0
Item 4    0     0      0      5
```

In the above example I would ship products from WH1 and WH3.  Here's why:

Item 1 is only available in WH1, so no choice.
Item 2 is available at HQ but also WH2. Since Item 3 will also ship from WH2 I want to consolidate shipments.
Item 3 is available in the full quantity from WH3 so I won't ship anything from HQ.
Item 4 is only available from WH4, so no choice.

The above is just one example.  As you can imagine, different quantities and availability may necessitate sometimes splitting an order between two WHs (i.e. HQ and WH2 if only partial quantities are available).

Any help would be greatly appreciated it!

Comment: Sounds like a good situation for a user-defined function in SQL,  Have your if/else logic in the function and return the preferred shipping location.  The, create a view with your existing table, plus return the results of the function as a column in the view.  This way you also don't have to change your app code if the business logic changes.